# Can I boot Windows 7 into safe mode with networking AND Sound?

Tags: windows-7, safe-mode

Is it possible to boot into **Safe Mode** with Networking and Sound?

---

```
System Information
------------------
Time of this report: 7/13/2013, 11:28:01
       Machine name: ANON-PC
   Operating System: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit (6.1, Build 7601) Service Pack 1 (7601.win7sp1_gdr.130318-1533)
           Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
System Manufacturer: Alienware
       System Model: M17xR4
               BIOS: InsydeH2O Version 03.72.02A02
          Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
             Memory: 6144MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 6114MB RAM
          Page File: 2546MB used, 9680MB available
        Windows Dir: C:\Windows
    DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
   User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
 System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
    DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
     DxDiag Version: 6.01.7601.17514 64bit Unicode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, **but I did not try it myself so be warned**, download the .REG file [here](http://hammer-and-nail86.deviantart.com/art/Enable-Music-In-Safemode-198876702).

OR

1. Press Windows + R, type `devmgmt.msc`, press Enter and look for your sound device. (e.g. Reatlek High Definition Audio) Double-click it.
2. Go to the tab 'Details' and click the drop-down list. Select 'Driver key' and copy the text from 'Value'
3. Copy the text into a word processor (e.g. Notepad)
4. Replace all lower-case letters with capital letters and remove the `\0000`.
5. Open Registry Editor (Windows + R > regedit) and locate `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot\Network`.
6. Create a new key (Rightclick > New > Key)
7. Copy the text from your word processor and paste it into the key name.
8. Edit the '(Default)' key and type 'Sound, video and game controllers'.
9. Create a new key called `AudioEndpointBuilder`, `MMCSS` and `Audiosrv`
10. Edit all their `(Default)` keys and type `Service`.
11. Restart your computer
12. Go to Services (Windows + R > `services.msc`) and start Multimedia Class Scheduler and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder.
13. Then start Windows Audio Service

[Source](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_can_you_make_the_sound_work_in_safe_mode)

Comment: It's better to link to the source page rather than the file itself, and always credit the source if you're simply copy-pasting a complete answer.